# Comma decimal separator is ignored by ASP.NET MVC model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

120,12 from http request is converted to 12012 in double model. I read that ASP.NET MVC should handle such things but I couldn't make it work

Request:

```
Accept-Language:da,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
...
Price: "120,12"
```

Action method' model contains: `public double Price { get; set; }`

Inside action:

```
var uICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture; // {da}
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; // {da-DK}
```

Localization is controlled in `Global.asax` inside `Application_AcquireRequestState`:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("da"); 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `double.Parse("120,12",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da"))` returns 120.12. Rather than trying to hard-code the locale with `AcquireRequestState`, you should try to find what's wrong - perhaps web.config uses a specific culture? There is a directive on the view? Trying to nail a locale at various settings typically results in more confusion and bugs

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In that project AcquireRequestState is used to setup locale according to users choice - I just simplified it for question as hard-coded da locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom model binder.

```
    public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var modelState = new ModelState {Value = valueResult};
            object actualValue = null;
            try
            {
                //Check if this is a nullable decimal and a null or empty string has been passed
                var isNullableAndNull = (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType &&
                                          string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue));

                //If not nullable and null then we should try and parse the decimal
                if (!isNullableAndNull)
                {
                    actualValue = decimal.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
            return actualValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Just change the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to that of the one the user has selected in the decimal.Parse statement.  Then register the new modelbinder at startup.